# how to change existing variable in a configuration file using batch file

Tags: batch-file, configuration-files

I am installing software on a client machine, so I have a configuration file having over 100 variables, so I want to change these variables at run time using batch file.

Here are some of variables for example-

file name: config.asp
...

```
USPSAccessKey=fsfsfs113bh$dd
USPSUserID=1232445
USPSPassword=#########
USPSServiceCode=PRIORITY
USPSServiceCodeFixed=YES
USPSPackageType=VARIABLE
USPSCustomerClassCode=FLAT
```

...

So there is any way to read this file and then change variables using batch file

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please say what system you are using... Windows, Linux, OSX?

Comment: how do you want to change them? with prompting? and replacing the file? Give more details please.

Comment: I am using windows server...

Comment: I don't want prompting, just in silent mode.
I am just copying setup files to required location. All done for now, 
Now I am left with open config.asp file and then change some variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. If you want to *modify config.asp file* in order to change certain lines with different values, then you may do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define new values of desired variables
set newValue[USPSUserID]=5442321
set newValue[USPSPassword]=$$$$$$$$$

(for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (config.asp) do (
   set "value=%%b"
   if defined newValue[%%a] set value=!newValue[%%a]!
   echo %%a=!value!
)) > newConfig.asp
```

Comment: But this only works with different files, so it would need to copy and delete. Is there no way to keep the origin file?

Comment: The only way is to read the whole file in first and then write it out, effectively overwriting the file.

Comment: ... and this only takes a `del oldfile` and `ren newfile oldfile` commands!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

First read the file with a for loop, then modify some values, then write the variables out using `set` with redirecting the output.  Note: I use `config2.asp` for the output so you can test if it works first.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%I in (config.asp) do set "%%I"

:: Set some USPS variables here
::


set USPS > config2.asp
```

Comment: +1 but better use `set "%%I"` as the config file could contains "forbidden" symbols.